# Troubles with geolocation and getJSON in codepen

Tags: javascript, json, geolocation, codepen

I'm having some troubles with codepen, I'm trying to get the weather on the user location, and I not getting the latitude and longitude, and can't get the getJSON to retrieve any JSON from the requested URL. Here is the code:

https://codepen.io/martini-alessandro/pen/VmGqyo

```
function getLocation() {
  if (navigator.geolocation) {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(getWeather);
  } else {
    alert("Your Web Browse does not support geolocation.");
  }
};
  function getWeather(position) {
  var baseURL = "api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?";
  var apiKey = "2ca568839db1b37c90c1d38842418e08";
  var latitude = position.coords.latitude;
  var longitude = position.coords.longitude;
  var urlRequest = baseURL + "lat=" + latitude + "&lon=" + longitude + "&APPID=" + apiKey;
  //alert(urlRequest);
  $.getJSON(urlRequest, function(json) {
    alert(json);
  });
};
```

Comment: you never seem to run `getLocation` - defining a function doesn't execute it. Also, once you fix that, there's a problem with the URL in your request (error 404)

Answer (score 1):

I was having this issue as well. It turns out that codepen blocks certain http requests. If you add "https://crossorigin.me/https://" to the beginning of your url it routes it through cross origin and then should return your JSON data providing the rest of your code is sound.